# How much trade data is enough for mission?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I accepted this mission

[image]

After travelling to Kini, I found the shattered remains of a ship and scooped up a canister of "trade data". I then returned to Aristotle gateway.

[image]

However the Missions screen didn't offer me a chance to receive my reward.

Why?

Comment: I haven't done one of these sorts of missions, but my guess is you picked up a non-unique instance of "Trade Data" which does not apply for this mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that "these goods are unique to this mission" means you're looking for a mission-specific signal source, not just any signal source holding trade data.

Sometimes scanning the nav beacon (drop in and get a scan of the actual beacon) can help (leads to a mission update message giving you a more specific location).

Scan all the signal sources until you find a mission-specific one. It will be really obvious after you scan it (different color, clearly says it's for your mission, etc).

It's also possible that you found a bugged mission. Sometimes that happens, and there's no way to actually complete it.

I'm not sure I've actually done a "trade data" mission, but I have definitely done some "exploration data" missions, so the mechanics should be similar.